# wildcards to use in codeigniter routing?

Tags: php, codeigniter, routes, wildcard

in codeigniter you can use wildcard to reroute.

i never heard the word wildcards before.

is this a set of rules you can use like regexp?

cause in codeigniter documentation they just gave some examples eg.

$route['product/(:num)'] = "catalog/product_lookup_by_id/$1";

is there a list/reference with all the available wildcard expressions you can use?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can match literal values or you can use **two** wildcard types:

**:num

:any**

**:num** will match a segment containing only numbers.
**:any** will match a segment containing any character.

Or you can use your custom regex, example:

```
$route['products/([a-z]+)/(\d+)'] = "$1/id_$2";
```

Comment: so the answer to my question is that there are only TWO wildcard expressions: :num and :any?

Comment: @asjsie: Yes you got it right. The other option is your own custom regex.